# What's the problem with 'execute "w! " + a:name' in a vim script/function?

Tags: vim

I have the following Vim-function:

```
fu! Create_file_and_write_to_it(name, text)

  new 
  execute "normal i" . a:text
  execute "w! " + a:name

endfu
```

I call this function like so:

```
:call Create_file_and_write_to_it('c:\temp\foo.txt', "here is some text")
```

While it creates a new buffer and writes the desired text (ie: *here is some text*) into the buffer, it doesn't write the buffer to a file named *c:\temp\foo.txt* or any other name I could see. Neither do I get an error message.

Is there a reason for this behaviour, or am I doing something wrong, and how would I go about getting the desired functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind... I found it.

I should have written

```
execute "w! " . a:name
```

instead of

```
execute "w! " + a:name
```

Comment: You forgot about the possibility of having spaces in filename: you should have written either `execute "w! ".fnameescape(a:name)` or `w! <backtick>=a:name<backtick>` (replace `<backtick>` with `\``).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
execute "w! " + a:name
```

do this:

```
exec "save! " . a:name
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Unless a:text has some special sequences/mappings to be triggered, you could also have used `put=a:text`

Comment: But this will start a new line. You can however do `normal! i^R^O=a:text^M`